# Link from canvas.toDataURL() dosen't work with .style.backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

When i use my code to edit the source of an img it works

Example:

```
//HTML
<img id="canvasImg">

//JavaScript
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(dataURL);
document.getElementById("canvasImg").src = dataURL;
```

But if i try to use java script to edit source of background image i can't get it  to work

```
//HTML
<div id="canvasImg"></div>

//JavaScript
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(dataURL);
document.getElementById("canvasImg").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+dataURL+"')";
```

here is my entire code: 
http://codebeautify.org/alleditor/50fff6

Comment: document.getElementById("canvasImg").style - A dot is missing before `style`

Comment: that wasn't the reason but thx for pointing out the tipo

Comment: your div is empty and no style was applied to give it a size. So try to specify an height and a width to `myDiv`

Comment: Thank a lot that was it!